# uniq command not working properly?

Tags: command-line, bash, uniq

So I'm checking the `md5` hash of my files with this as my output:

```
657cf4512a77bf47c39a0482be8e41e0  ./dupes2.txt
657cf4512a77bf47c39a0482be8e41e0  ./dupes.txt
8d60a927ce0f411ec94ac26a4785f749  ./derpina.txt
15f63928b8a1d5337137c38b5d66eed3  ./foo.txt
8d60a927ce0f411ec94ac26a4785f749  ./derp.txt
```

However, after running `find . -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | uniq -w 33` to find the unique hashes I get this:

```
657cf4512a77bf47c39a0482be8e41e0  ./dupes2.txt
8d60a927ce0f411ec94ac26a4785f749  ./derpina.txt
15f63928b8a1d5337137c38b5d66eed3  ./foo.txt
8d60a927ce0f411ec94ac26a4785f749  ./derp.txt
```

From my understanding, only one of either `derpina.txt` or `derp.txt` should be showing up since their hashes are the same. Am I missing something? Can anyone enlighten me as to why it outputs like this?

Comment: Figured it out. Apparently uniq does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent. Link to answer that helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114677/linux-uniq-identical-lines-not-matching

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You need to use `sort` before `uniq`:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} ';' | sort | uniq -w 33
```

`uniq` only removes repeated lines.  It does not re-order the lines looking for repeats.  `sort` does that part.

This is documented in [`man uniq`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/uniq.1.html):

> **Note**: `uniq` does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent.  You may want to sort the input first, or use `sort -u` without `uniq`.

Comment: `uniq` should be aliased as `sort -u` by default in all systems. If at all it always needs "sort" for it to work properly.

Comment: That change would lessen some confusion.  On the other hand, `uniq` has many features not available with `sort -u`.  Also, there are cases where one wants to use `uniq` without `sort`.

Answer (score 7):

The input for `uniq` needs to be sorted. So for the example case,

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | sort | uniq -w 33
```

would work. The `-w` (`--check-chars=N`) makes the lines unique only regarding the first column; This option works for this case. but the possibilities to specify the relevant parts of the line for `uniq` are limited. For example, there are no options to specify working on some column 3 and 5, ignoring column 4.

The command `sort` has an option for unique output lines itself, and the lines are unique regarding the keys used for sorting. This means we can make use of the powerful key syntax of `sort` to define regarding which part the lines should be uniq.

For the example,

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum '{}' ';' | sort -k 1,1 -u
```

gives just the same result, but the `sort` part is more flexible for other uses.

Answer (score 3):

The `uniq` command won't work unless input is buffered (e.g. using `sort`) or duplicated lines are next to each other. So find below few solutions.

#### AWK

Here is syntax for `awk`:

```
command | awk '!a[$0]++{print}'
```

For repeated use, you can define the following shell alias:

```
alias unicat='awk "!a[\$0]++{print}"'
```

then run: `command | unicat`.

Parallel syntax (for quicker parsing):

```
command | time parallel --block 100M --pipe awk '!a[\$0]++{print}'
```

Test command (100 lines filtered out of 200):

```
echo | pee "seq 1 100" "seq 1 100" | awk '!a[$0]++{print}' | wc -l
```

#### Perl

Try the following Perl script:

```
command | perl -e 'while(<>){if(!$s{$_}){print $_;$|=1;$s{$_}=1;}}'
```

Shell alias syntax for repeated use:

```
alias unicat='perl -e '\''while(<>){if(!$s{$_}){print $_;$|=1;$s{$_}=1;}}'\'''
```

then run: `command | unicat`.

#### `unique`

For alternative to `uniq`, you can also use karrick's `unique` written in Go (it's using similar approach as above, but it's much faster and uses less memory than Perl/AWK solutions):

- https://github.com/karrick/unique

Usage:

```
command | unique
```

Cons: When processing huge data, it's using a lot of memory, as it's hashing each item and adding it into array.

Workaround can be to have short lived instances per certain block size (if few duplicates are acceptable), e.g.

```
command | parallel --block 100M -j 1 --pipe unique
```

or using `split` (10M per chunk), e.g.

```
command | split -b 10M --filter="unique"
```

#### `quniq`

Use `quniq` utility to remove duplicated. It works better than `uniq`, as it buffers the input lines.

- Project page: https://github.com/syucream/quniq
- Install by: `go install github.com/syucream/quniq@latest`

Cons: It seems to be stuck till end of the pipe.

#### `huniq`

If you're looking for faster solution to sort then remove duplicates, use `huniq`.

- Project page: https://github.com/koraa/huniq
- Install by: `cargo install huniq`

---

More similar projects:

- https://github.com/mitsutoshi/uni (written in Rust)
- https://github.com/whitfin/runiq (written in Rust)
- https://github.com/miolini/uniqbloom (written in Go, using Bloom filter)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could install killdupes, my program to destroy every last effing duplicate there is!

https://github.com/batchmcnulty/killdupes

:-)